# How to cover requests with two / after domain name in API address

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I have a .NET Core web application which recently upgraded to .NET Core 2.2
When the project was on core 2.1 it could support requests with two / after domain name but after upgrading to core 2.2 it lost this ability!

For example, before the upgrade, both of these addresses were valid

```
http://mywebsite.com//api/home/getinfo

http://mywebsite.com/api/home/getinfo
```

But now after the upgrade, it returns 404 not found on below address

```
http://mywebsite.com//api/home/getinfo
```

And only works on

```
http://mywebsite.com/api/home/getinfo
```

I've changed

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

To

```
[Route("/api/[controller]")]
```

This was not successful.

I appreciate any suggestion or recommendation.

Comment: Is there any reason why would you need that?

Comment: Because I know that some API consumers call my methods like this!

Comment: Have you actually tested it? Because, it might look different, but I dont see a reason why it would make a difference

Comment: Yes, I've tested it a lot. Even I've changed the MapRoute in startup file but it doesn't work!

Comment: You could try creating a middleware that replaces "//" with "/"